# Is there any correlation between conection and function?

Tags: neuroscience, connectionism

I have been searching why different functions exist in even a similar structure cortex.

The first reason is differences in cortical neuron density.

> The neuronal density contour plot (Fig. 1D) reveals the approximate boundaries of V1, V2, and other extrastriate areas and makes it possible to distinguish somatosensory cortex from surrounding areas. ([Collins, et. al., 2010](https://doi.org/10.1073/pnas.1010356107)).

And then, naturally, the second reason is differences in cortical connections.
For example, it might to have a paper that the division by connectome matches that of Broadman. However, I couldn't find the paper.

Please let me know if I've missed something, or if the connectome itself is not yet mature enough to do it.

### References

Collins, C. E., Airey, D. C., Young, N. A., Leitch, D. B., & Kaas, J. H. (2010). Neuron densities vary across and within cortical areas in primates. *Proceedings of the National Academy of Sciences, 107*(36), 15927-15932. https://doi.org/10.1073/pnas.1010356107